# Plot graph iteratively during every update

Tags: python, matplotlib

The data set is mixed by three clusters, each of which comes from a gaussian density function parametrized by mu_k and sigma_k, k = 0, 1, 2.

I want to plot these 2D samples with its contour in a graph, these samples are colored by its cluster.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

% Docstring of function GM_generated_data().
% This function generated the data.
% y is a ndarray, with its elements y[i] = array([y1, y2]),
% z is a indicator variable which represents which cluster each y[i] belongs to, 
% z[i] \in {0, 1, 2}.
y, z = GM_generated_data(paras)

% Plot each point with its cluster color iteratively, 
colors = 'bgrcmykw'
for i in range(len(y)):
    plt.plot(y[i][0], y[i][1], 'o', color = colors[z[i]])
plt.show()
```

Q1. Is there a better way to do this?

Now I need to update the indicator variable z, this is precisely called the Gibbs sampling for Gaussian mixture models.

```
iterations = 20
for iteration in range(iterations):
    ... % Operations update z
    plt.plot(y[i][0], y[i][1], 'o', color = colors[z[i]])
plt.show()
```

What I want to show is during each iteration, I can see the changing process of each plot step.

Q2.Is there a method in Python to do this? like MATLAB's hold on... pause(0.5)... hold off?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about which color is which cluster, or you feel like constructing a color map (which is actually pretty easy), you can just do this without the for loop (your first piece of code):

```
plt.scatter(y[:,0],y[:,1],c=z,cmap='Paired')
```

(or substitute 'Paired' for you color map).